# Angular 8 NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays error and Acces Control Allow origin

Tags: angular, spring-restcontroller, cross-origin-read-blocking

I have a model:

```
export class Employe {    
    constructor(public id?: any,
        public nom?: String,
        public prenom?: String,
        public cin?: String){}    
}
```

**employees.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.loadEmployes();
}    

 pageEmployes:any={};

  loadEmployes():Observable<any>{    
     this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/employe").subscribe(
      data=>{
        console.log(data);
        this.pageEmployes = data;

      }, err=>{
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
    return this.pageEmployes;
  }
```

**employees.component.html**

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of pageEmployes">         
      <td>{{item.nom}}</td>
      <td>{{item.prenom}}</td>    
    </tr>
```

**CollaborateurController.java**

```
@RestController

@RequestMapping("/api/employe")

@CrossOrigin("*")

public class CollaborateurController {

    @Autowired
    private CollaborateurRepository collaborateurRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Collaborateur> getEmp() {
        return (List<Collaborateur>) collaborateurRepository.findAll();
    }
```

This throws me error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/employe' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to iterate (loop) an object, **not** an array by the looks of you code example.

This part is false:

```
pageEmployes:any={};
```

And should be changed to:

```
pageEmployes: Employe[] = [];
```

The "= {};" initializes a new **object**.

The "= [];" initializes a new iterable **list**

Comment: @Kindth Glad i could help, remember to mark answer as the solution. This can help other people with similar problems to quickly identify a good answer

Comment: thats working also i should add this line on main @SpringBootApplication(exclude= {
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class
}) for people who are using spring security

Answer (score 2):

You try to iterate through object not array. Change `pageEmployes: any={}` to `pageEmployes = []`.

And this `return this.pageEmployee;` is not necessary just remove it together with returning value in function.

function with http call change to this:

```
loadEmployes() {    
     this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/employe").subscribe(
      data=>{
        console.log(data);
        this.pageEmployes = data;

      }, err=>{
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: The `ngIf` is redundant here. Just initializing `pageEmployes` as an empty array would be sufficient since the `ngFor` will have no data to iterate over and will hence display nothing.

Comment: Oh yeah ok got It XD

Comment: I want to display response data in the front end and it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

What data you get when you print your response with `console.log(data);`?

Because of

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/employe' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

there is invalid response. 
Read about CORS policy in spring
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

About Angular error, you want to iterate over object so you need to change type of `pageEmployes`

```
pageEmployes:any={};
```

into

```
pageEmployes: Employe[] = [];
```

Comment: Okay i'll try it

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error. I was iterating the object not the array so i have fixed that in this way

> **From**

```
 this.faqService.getFaq().subscribe((faqs:any)=>{
      this.faqs = faqs; // here i was trying to iterate over object 
    })
```

> To

```
>   this.faqService.getFaq().subscribe((faqs:any)=>{
      this.faqs = faqs.data;
      
    })
```

`Console.Log()` *and See your response closely and then iterate over array you will be good to go*